# Why do I get the an error with the code below

Tags: vba, excel-2010

I have the following code and keep getting the message "Object variable or With Block variable not set

```
Sub Find()
Dim Order As String
Order = frmForm.txtSO   
Sheets("Download").Select
Range("D2:D4130").Find(What:="Order").Select
End Sub
```

The frmForm.txtSO is a field in a user form I have created. I'm not sure why I keep getting the error message

Comment: Possibly the "frmForm" is not known in the Sub.

Answer (score 0):

**Fixing The Error:**

You need to remove the quotes around "Order", currently you are searching for the string "Order" and not the variable, this should work:

```
Sub Find()
Dim Order As String
Order = frmForm.txtSO   
Sheets("Download").Select
Range("D2:D4130").Find(What:=Order).Select
End Sub
```

**Accounting for search string not found:**

You may also want to add some code to handle the scenario where the "Order" can't be found, something like this:

```
Sub Find()
    Dim Order As String
    Dim findRng As Range
    
    Order = frmForm.txtSO
    Set findRng = Sheets("Download").Range("D2:D4130").Find(What:=Order)
        
    If Not findRng Is Nothing Then
        Sheets("Download").Activate
        findRng.Select
    Else
        MsgBox ("Order not found")
    End If
    
End Sub
```

**Ensuring multiple search strings can be found:**

To ensure you are able to "loop" through the duplicate records in column D you'll need to modify the code again. Essentially, you need to change the `Find` range so that it starts it's search from the currently selected cell and works it's way down from there:

```
Sub Find()
    Dim Order As String
    Dim findRng As Range

    Order = frmForm.txtSO
    Set findRng = Range("D" & ActiveCell.Row & ":D4130").Find(What:=Order)

    If Not findRng Is Nothing Then
        findRng.Select
    Else
        MsgBox ("Order not found")
    End If
    
End Sub
```

However, if when the userform is opened the currently selected cell is on a row lower than the record you're searching for, the above code will be unable to find said record. To get around this, instead of activating the "Download" sheet from this sub, simply active the sheet and select cell `D1` from the same sub that launches the userform, like so:

```
Sheets("Download").Activate
Range("D1").Select
frmForm.Show
```

This will ensure that when the userform is initially launched the search will begin from `D1`, however each subsequent time that `Find` is run it will begin the search from whatever was selected in the previous run

Comment: Doubt frmForm.txtSO will ever work. You should try to inspect the variable. It's probably frmForm.txtSO.text you want to use (if txtSO is a TextBox).

Comment: @LoBellin I was skeptical at first as well, but I tested the above code before posting the answer and can confirm it works without having to add `.text` to the end of the reference

Comment: That worked, thank you. Sometimes the order is listed more than once because there are multiple products against the order. Any ideas on how to loop to list each entry ?

Comment: No problem, I've updated my answer to account for this, let me know if you have any issues